# How to use express.js with native mongoDB driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I struggle while trying to do a simple mongoDB query from within my express app:

#### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongourl = ''; // omitted on SO
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbInstance;

MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
    db.on('open',function(){
        dbInstance = db;
    })
});


app.get('/', routes.index(dbInstance));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){

});
```

#### routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(db){
  return function(req,res){

  }

};
```

Do i understand correctly that the exports.index' paramter is a database instance? If so, why can't i do `db.getCollectionNames()`?

How would i work with the database instance in my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js is asynchronous. This means that `db` and so `dbInstance` do not exist **after** the `Mongoclient.connect()` function call, but **within** the `callback`. So your code has to look like:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
    ...
    app.get( '/', routes.index( db ) );
    ...
});
```

Comment: Would this be considered best practice? If not, is there a way to accomplish this without having to wrap up nearly everything in the connect?